# ¿Porque segun el debuggeador entra al else?

Tags: java, spring

[image: Debugeado en IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.2 Maquina Ubuntu 18.04] ¿Porque segun el debuggeador entra al else? segun yo deberia entrar al if. ¿Estoy muy mal?. cuando debuguie, no es montaje ni photoshop. ¿A que puede atribuirse?.

Uso Spring boot, Java 1.8

Comment: ¿Y qué es lo que sucede?

Comment: si, no veo nada extraño.

Comment: Segun el debuggeador entra al else, y segun yo deberia entrar al if.
¿Estoy muy mal?.

Answer (score 1):

`existe` es una variable que está en el `scope` del método... pero no la estás usando... estás llamando al método `exists` de la instancia (que ahí no se ve como está definido) y que devolvió `false`.

Comment: no se de donde el down vote... pero gracias!

Comment: Y entonces porque en la variable booleana "existe" toma  el this.exists de la instancia como true , y luego en el comparador logico del if toma false?

Comment: como no podemos ver la definición de `exists` no te puedo decir con _seguridad_ lo que está pasando... pero _probablemente_ (en realidad es un 99.9 % seguro) lo que sucede es que el método `exists` **cambia** el estado de la instancia así que la primera llamada dice `true` y en la siguiente dice `false`.